# Is there a working docker environment for Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, docker

I already tried to get Magento 2 running now for more then 6 months, but still failing. Is there a working docker-container for Magento 2.2.1 that doesn't only give you a working webpage but also can run the intregration tests ?

Comment: Try this - https://bitnami.com/stack/magento/installer

Comment: Thanx i will try it out.  I'm now trying: 'https://github.com/magento/magento2devbox-web' but it doesn't install magento but has everything in one container (so, less permission issues). And i'm trying out: 'https://github.com/clean-docker/Magento2' but it just started, so have to wait a while to find out if it works.